# How to add existing users in my rails app using Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, stripe-payments, payment-processing, stripes

With stripe payment such that the users don't have to login again and still have a stripe id allocated to them if they don not have one in order to select products
This is my user .rb code :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  def to_s
    email
  end

  after_create do
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: self.email)
    update(stripe_customer_id: customer.id)
```

SO this creates a stripe id for every new user created on the website so is their any way  i can do the same for already existing user inorder to prevent them from logging out or creating a new account in order to access tripe payment gateway integration with the rails website

Comment: Can you provide more detail here? What IDs do you need to associate with a user? How will you use them later? What have you tried already?

Comment: SO i have mentioned by code of creating a stripe user by calling stripe api for every new user created , so can i do the same for the existing  user in order to prevent them from creating new account or logout form my rails website ?